# Variable loses value after for loop in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote following script in Oracle SQL:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION working_time
RETURN INT
IS
diff INT;
sum_ INT;
CURSOR cur IS SELECT * FROM users_;
BEGIN
sum_ := 0;
FOR usr IN cur LOOP
    SELECT SUM(NVL(end_, CURRENT_DATE) - start_)
    INTO diff
    FROM experience
    WHERE user_ = usr.id_;

    sum_ := sum_ + diff;

    IF usr.id_ != 100 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User ' || usr.first_name || ' ' || usr.last_name || ' has worked for ' || diff || ' days.');
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('return: ' || sum_);
END LOOP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('return: ' || sum_);
RETURN sum_;
END working_time;
```

The value of sum_ inside for loop is printed correctly, but outside the loop it prints nothing. The variable was declared before for loop, so I don't understand what's going on. Can anyone explain how to fix it and why is it happening?

EDIT: posted full code

Comment: Okey, I edited.

Comment: Your code is working. You should check your parameters.

Comment: I use it in code this way: SELECT working_time() FROM DUAL; and get "value:  " at the end, while inside the loop the value is correct

Comment: But this function takes no arguments, I'm not passing anything... should I?

Comment: Yup, it's uni project. I try to make a function and show that it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found what was wrong:

In some cases diff was not a number (and this was the last case, so I thought that the for loop was the reason).

Changing the code to

```
sum_ := sum_ + NVL(diff, 0);
```

solved the issue.